# How to unregister a chart plugin?

Tags: chart.js

Using Chart.pluginService.register I drew a line on chart for some requirement on Page B (lets say). I go to Page B from Page A.

Now when I go back to page A and again go to Page B, the line drawn on the chart starts getting darker.

How to unregister that plugin when I go back to Page A?

I saw an unregister and clear function on this source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/647dc582cd85fc8e25d49cf0e38d459c582b2652/src/core/core.plugin.js

Unregister function has no effect. Clear function clears the previously drawn line but the legend of the chart disappears.

Comment: Can you please post the implementation code to be able to help you in a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Link to stackblitz code: https://angular-4xjncj.stackblitz.io/products

I have drawn a horizontal line on chart with setting as rgb(0,0,255,0.3). I need the alpha value as 0.3

Steps to reproduce:
1. Click on 'Go To Details' (This will navigate to details page)
2. Click on 'Go To Products List'

Repeat above steps atleast 4-5 times, you will see the faint blue line getting darker and darker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  Chart.pluginService.unregister(this.horizonalLinePlugin);
}
```

in your `ProductDetailComponent` shoud do the trick.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uxfwqb?file=src/app/product-detail/product-detail.component.ts

The problem here is that if you have multiple chart components visible at the same time, the plugin will be visible in all the other charts.

The better fix:

1. register the plugin only once, outside of ngInit... directly in the module file or somewhere globally. This will impact all the charts in the entire application but will make it unnecessary to unregister it so it is clear that it's something global that impacts all charts.
2. create your own wrapper component/directive over chart.js (or a pull request for angular2-chartjs) that can accept a `plugins` input and pass it to the `Chart` constructor http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html:
   `var chart1 = new Chart(ctx, { plugins: [plugin] });` This will allow you to have a chart with the plugin and a chart without it, so no need to register/unregister global plugins.

Comment: Your solution works great on stackblitz sample code! In actual one, I am drawing a vertical gridline and its label. The scenario is where data keeps on coming every second and it is plotted on the chart. The data is subscribed inside a observable, so I need to keep the plugin in ngOnInit. I added your solution in my actual code, line is still getting darker. What I observed is for first time, plugin is added properly in plugins array. The second time I go to product detaila page, the plugin is added again :(. I got to see the registered plugins by JSON.stringify(Chart.pluginService.getAll())

Comment: Any idea on how to give id to plugin when we register the plugin?

Comment: @RuchiDhore do you have multiple `ProductDetailComponent` instantiated at the same time? You could register the plugin statically only once...

Comment: @RuchiDhore So if you still want to unregister the plugin each time, but have it registered only once, you can do it like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-em7ere?file=src/app/product-detail/product-detail.component.ts

Comment: Otherwise you can just register it globally once per app and don't unregister it ever like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lg4mgs?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer twice.

Comment: Stackblitz URLs throw not found

Comment: @saravanapriyan it was the code from the author with the added code from my answer.